# How do i track or get the status of changes that are suggested in a docx xml file? how do I get the status of the comment. i.e resolved or not?

Tags: xml, ms-word

I need to build an application that tracks and checks the status of the comments in a word document. Is there any way to track the status of the comments and stuff from the xml files that are generated from the docx xmls?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you added some programming-language.

The normal content of a docx is at this location `/word/document.xml`

If someone makes a comment it has a start-tag: `<w:commentRangeStart w:id="1"/>`  and a end-tag: `<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="1"/>`, and the comment is about the content in between.

i.e. a part of document.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:p w14:paraId="4AF7A7F7" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="0085638B" w:rsidRDefault="002F72D2" w:rsidP="00203E2E">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Some Article</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:commentRangeStart w:id="1"/>
  <w:commentRangeStart w:id="2"/>
  <w:r w:rsidR="0085638B">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> in which this peace of text has a comment with also a reaction</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="1"/>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00980906">
    <w:commentReference w:id="1"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="2"/>
</w:p>
```

The location of the xml-file with the actual comments in docx are here `/word/comments.xml`

That file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:comment w:id="1" w:author="Siebe Jongebloed" w:date="2023-08-11T09:55:00Z" w:initials="SJ">
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="commentStyle"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:annotationRef/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Hier the content of the actual comment</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:comment>
  <w:comment w:id="2" w:author="Siebe Jongebloed" w:date="2023-08-12T12:49:00Z" w:initials="SJ">
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="commentStyle"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:annotationRef/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Agree</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:comment>
</w:comments>
```

The binding is based on the `w:id`-attribute.

In the above example

1. `<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="1"/>` is referring to the comment `<w:comment w:id="1"/>`
2. `<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="2"/>` is referring to the comment `<w:comment w:id="2"/>`